# Principles on how to send a mass mailer without it ending up in junk mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, language-agnostic, actionmailer, massmail

I put together a really nice mass mailer, but occasionally mails end up in junkmail on various different mail providers for various reasons. Does anyone know if there is a write up anywhere on best practices to send mass mailers?

Comment: ::shrugs:: I'd just as soon that my SPAM filters *did* catch mass emailing. Even the ones I sign up for, until I whitelist them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) have a good [document](http://downloads.mailchimp.com/guides/Guide_Deliverability.pdf) which covers key points (IP ranges, rate limiting, SPF/DKIM, bounce handling, feedback loops).

As an aside, it's unusual to see something so comprehensive from a company whose business is based around doing this kind of stuff for other people - presumably they hope it'll make you think twice before building something from scratch!

Comment: SimonJ, this is the best possible resource I could have ever found. Thank you so much!