# What is the effect of a Precedence: bulk header on e-mail messages

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

According to [Google Mail guidelines](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126#format), bulk mail must contain the header

```
Precedence: bulk
```

What does it do? I could not find a RFC describing the effect on mail delivery.

Some background: I'm working on scripts that will send 500k+ mails daily. They are different kind of messages: account related mail (delivery critical), but also notifications of new content (delivery not critical).

Comment: You might also find interesting the document linked to from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175433/princibles-on-how-to-send-a-mass-mailer-without-it-ending-up-in-junk-mail

Comment: The linked Google Mail guideslines no longer recommend use `Precedence: bulk`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exact meaning of `Precedence:` isn't standardised, but it prevents some mail servers from sending vacation and bounce messages, and may be used by service providers to deprioritise bulk mail during busy times so that "personal" mail continues to be delivered quickly.

From [RFC2076](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2076):

> Non-standard, controversial, discouraged.
> Sometimes used as a priority value which can influence transmission speed and delivery. Common values are "bulk" and "first-class". Other uses is to control automatic replies and to control return-of-content facilities, and to stop mailing list loops.

Comment: This header (Precedence) will increase the inbox deliverablity or not ?

Answer (score 4):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154718/precedence-header-in-email), as well as [RFC 3834](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834).

In short, the `Precedence:` header is non-standard. Google's recommendation is perhaps just a way to give a hint to their spam filters that you really did intend to send out 500k+ emails from your server (as opposed to one abused by spammers).